# having trouble implementing the right word to a url link

Tags: python, api, selenium-webdriver

i have a program that asks users which department they want to choose from, i made the question into a while loop that would keep asking the same question until they put a valid response in. and whenever they wanted to break  the loop they would type the word "exit". once they type in a valid response it would add ask another question in another function that would ask for the class your want info on  based on the department you're in, it  would then  lead it to a website where i can get the information i need. the issue im facing is that it doesn't take the valid response that was typed in, it would instead implement the word "exit" which was used to break out of the loop as it was the last input. i want it to take the input before that and not "EXIT"

here is the code

```
def get_departments():
    umd_departments = requests.get("https://api.umd.io/v0/courses/departments")
    umd_departments_list = umd_departments.json()

    umd_departments_list2 = json.dumps(umd_departments_list, indent=1)
    department_storage = [department['dept_id'] for department in umd_departments_list]#comprehensive for loop to put the department ID into a list 
    print(department_storage)

    while True:     
        dept = input('what department are you  in right now: ')
        dept = dept.upper()
        if dept == 'EXIT':
            break         
        if dept not in department_storage:

            print("not approriate response")
        else:
            try:
                department_url = requests.get(f"https://api.umd.io/v0/courses?dept_id={dept}")
                specific_major =department_url.json()
                keep_keys = ["course_id"]
                courses = [{k: json_dict[k] for k in keep_keys}
                          for json_dict in specific_major]
                print(courses)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)

    return courses,dept
```

```
def get_classes(courses):  
    classes = [course['course_id'] for course in courses]
    print(classes)
    course_select = input('what class would you like to select').upper()
    if course_select not in classes:
        raise ValueError(" class does not exist")
    else:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
        url = f"https://app.testudo.umd.edu/soc/202008/{dept}"
        driver.get(url)
        section_container = driver.find_element_by_id(f"{course_select}")
        section_container.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[@class='toggle-sections-link']").click()# it would click on the show section button on the site that would reveal the sections
        sleep(1)
        section_info = section_container.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='sections sixteen colgrid']").text 

    return section_info
```

let's say for example in the get departments function i type in INST and its considered a valid response,   it would then ask for which class i want to choose from that department. it would then create a url that would get me the info i need like this:

```
https://app.testudo.umd.edu/soc/202008/INST
```

however i get this:

```
https://app.testudo.umd.edu/soc/202008/EXIT
```

the latter doesn't produce anything as it doesn't exist and it causes errors. is there a way to make it so that it doesn't make the  "EXIT"  input stored into a valuable and instead takes the valid response before it? greatly appreciated if anyone could help.

Comment: Add a bool flag to find out if your program can be exited, then you can do if exit input and flag is true break

Comment: so something like this:  if dept == 'EXIT' is True: break? @ShubhamSrivastava

Comment: Oh my bad i understood question wrong check the answer if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you just need another variable

```
userInput = input('what department are you in right now: ')
userInput = userInput.upper() 
if userInput == 'EXIT': 
    break 
else:
     dept = userInput
```

Comment: im sorry im a little confused, the dept variable in my code is the same as the UserInput in your sample, do i make the dept = dept  in the else section?  as when i do that i still get the same problem

Comment: what i understand is your select department loop will not exit without someone typing EXIT;  either you break the loop after you print courses in the try (which is what i suggest);  or wait for user to type exit in which case selected dept is overwritten, so when i use a variable userInput first it gets the dept which is then copied to dept variable; but when user types EXIT it will not be copied to dept and you can exit and dept will have correct value entered